# Preclinical research: can (should) the sham group be smaller than the treatment groups?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sample-size, multiple-comparisons, sample, unbalanced-classes

I am engaged in a preclinical (mouse) in vivo study. There are 5 experimental groups (sham, heart attack, heart attack plus intervention 1, heart attack plus intervention 1+A and heart attack plus intervention 1+B).

Pre-experiment statistical power calculations suggested that I need n=12 per group to adequately power my experiment.

My question is: can the sham group have a lower n number (for example n=5)? I have been advised by one senior that the sham group *should* have less because you want the highest possible n numbers in the treatment groups. I've been told by another senior person that you should aim for a balanced design where all groups are as close to the same size as possible. The results are likely to be non-parametric (not normally distributed).

Which is correct? What other information do I need to understand the correct approach?

Answer (score 2):

In terms of power against the overall null hypothesis in an ANOVA (all groups same), the most efficient design for $5n$ subjects in 5 groups is to have $n$ subjects per group.

The most sensible departure from this balanced design that I have seen is to put slightly *more* subjects in the control group because, among *ad hoc* comparisons, the most important are often to compare each treatment to the control group.

I am unaware of any good argument that putting *fewer* subjects into the control group is an advantage.

Specifically, if you have a balanced design with $12$ replications per group, in which treatment
groups have differences $0.5,0.5, 1,$ and $1.6$ standard deviations $\sigma$
above the control group, the power is about $89\%.$

```
set.seed(1234)
m = 10^5;  pv = numeric(m)
g = rep(1:5, each=12)
for(i in 1:m) {
 x1 = rnorm(12, 50, 1)
 x2 = rnorm(12, 50.5, 1)
 x3 = rnorm(12, 50.5, 1)
 x4 = rnorm(12, 51, 1)
 x5 = rnorm(12, 51.6, 1)
  x = c(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
 pv[i] = oneway.test(x ~ g)$p.val
 }
mean(pv <= 0.05)
[1] 0.886
```

By contrast, in the same situation, but with only $5$ mice in the control group,
the power drops to about $75\%.$ [This is not *exactly* the same as a chain being only as strong as its weakest link, but something like that.]

```
set.seed(1234)
m = 10^5;  pv = numeric(m)
g = rep(1:5, c(5,12,12,12,12))
for(i in 1:m) {
 x1 = rnorm(5, 50, 1)
 x2 = rnorm(12, 50.5, 1)
 x3 = rnorm(12, 50.5, 1)
 x4 = rnorm(12, 51, 1)
 x5 = rnorm(12, 51.6, 1)
  x = c(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
 pv[i] = oneway.test(x ~ g)$p.val
 }
mean(pv <= 0.05)
[1] 0.74824
```

*Notes:* (1) In these simulations, I have used the R procedure `oneway.test` which
gives accurate P-values even if groups have somewhat different variances. But
groups were simulated to have equal variances. If there is any question whether
different treatments might lead to different group variances, I recommend
this version of the one-way ANOVA.

(2) If your main concern is to use fewer mice overall, then with the same pattern
of effects as in the simulations above, you can get power about $85\%$ with $11$ mice per group.